# Custom Routes in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel routes with resource controller. I have two routes for my application as follow:

```
Route::resource('route1','route1Controller');
Route::resource('route2','route2Controller');
```

Now I want to generate custom route which can forward request to other route. The name of the route to be used should be passed by post parameter. Suppose I visit the following url : '**www.mysite.com/navigate**'. This url includes one post parameter called 'use_controller' having value 'route1'. So it should be something like following :

```
Route::get('navigate',function(){
  $use_controller == Request::all()['use_controller'];
    if($use_controller=="route1")
      use Route::resource('route1','route1Controller');
    else if($use_controller=="route2")
      use Route::resource('route2','route2Controller');
});
```

Is it possible to do something like this ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you mean you have a form inside `/navigate` route which holds an use_controller input to be sent via post? Otherwise it doesn't make sense what you are talking about

Comment: No. I don't have anything inside navigate. I want to use navigate as an entry point for every route request. From there every request should be routed.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a while ago. I had all my routes declared as 'resource' and I had one main route. Then I took the parameters from the URL request and made a redirect from that main route:

```
return redirect()->action("{$controller}@{$action}");
```

Of course you'll have to set up validations to check if the controller and action from the parameters actually exist.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. But here I have to declare all methods separately. e.g. controller@index, controller@show, controller@update etc ?

Comment: Well yes, if you want to use restfull controllers (like you do with Route::resource) you must have those methods in the controller. Do you have something else in mind?